# Populating numpy array using for loop returns an empty array?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am writing a python code where I plan to populate a numpy array using a for loop after some calculations. The process goes like this,

I have an array named prob1 and prob2 which looks like this (showing only prob1 array here):

```
[[ -2.15746726   0.07526147 -27.26482738]
 [ -2.86738724   0.35577766 -29.73604211]
 [ -2.89416653   0.38719942 -29.05970173]]
```

Based on the values present in the second column of the each row in the arrays and perform a calculation and store the obtained values in a 1-D array. The code for the same is as follows:

```
import math

a = 0.5
Da = np.array([])

for i in range(0,2):

     result1 = ((1/1-a)*math.log((pow(prob1[i,1],a))*(pow(prob2[i,1],(1-a)))))
     Da = np.append(Da, result1)

print(Da)
```

Now, on executing the last statement, I get an empty array []. Any idea where I have done an error?

EDIT: The prob2 array is like this:

```
[[ -2.12039722 -27.33255184   0.07201078]
 [ -2.81648812 -29.79371028   0.3558179 ]
 [ -2.8419714  -29.10474976   0.38771759]]
```

Comment: Can you also provide the prob2 array?

Comment: Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jawsem Prob2 array provided